# iOS: Releasing Object Thats In Use (ARC)

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease

I have an object that I have created that subscribes to some NSNotificationCenter notifications, but it is being released, since I don't have a pointer to the instantiation. The instantiation has a delegate that will call a method back to another class I have, so I felt it unnecessary to also have a pointer to it, since the pointer doesn't serve any purpose.

Basically, I have an instantiation of a class, DelegateListener (name is just for example purposes), which subscribes to some of the default `NSNotificationCeneter`'s notifications. This instantiation isn't assigned to any pointer after the instantiation ends. The instantiation, however, has a property, delegate. I assign a value to that delegate during the instantiation. That delegate implements methods that I want the DelegateListener to call when the notifications that it subscribed to fire.

The problem with this is that the instantiation of DelegateListener that I create gets released, unless if I assign it to a retained pointer. Is there a way to avoid this automatic release of my DelegateListener instantiation within ARC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store the `DelegateListener` instance in a static variable if you don't have multiple of them.

> I felt it unnecessary to also have a pointer to it, since the pointer doesn't serve any purpose.

The pointer does (or at least *should*) serve a purpose: when you no longer need to listen to the notifications, you should unsubscribe the `DelegateListener` from receiving them. At the very least, this should happen when your application goes to the background (unless the point of it is to perform background processing), and when your application terminates.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:delegateListener];
```

Comment: I have the delegate returning to nil and I'm unsubscribing from the notifications upon dealloc. But you're saying that I should maintain my static pointer to it, since its the only way, huh.

Comment: Well, if it unsubscribes on `dealloc` then when ARC cleans it up it's going to unsubscribe then. So your delegate becomes useless. Keep a static pointer to it and then set the listener to `nil` when you want it to unsubscribe and your `dealloc` will take care of it as you say.

Comment: @darvidsOn So, when there isn't a pointer, but it holds a delegate to a retained class, it will get released automatically? Isn't that annoying?

Comment: Unless the delegate retains its owner, that's very much standard behaviour. The runtime sees no object holding a reference to the delegate listener, so the assumption is made that no object will be able to reference anything at that memory address, and the memory is cleaned up.

Comment: Shouldn't the NSNotificationCenter have a pointer to it? Or maybe thats a part of the cleanup?

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3964444/244343) answer, it doesn't hold a pointer.

Comment: Blah. I wish that I could just explicitly retain it. But thanks for your help!