# How does the NSNotificationCenter detect the deallocated observer in ARC?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, nsnotificationcenter

I found that when using `NSNotificationCenter` in ARC, even you forget to remove the `observer` from `defaultCenter`, and the `observer` has `deallocated`,  then you post the notification that the observer observed , there is no crash anymore !!

before Xcode 4, there is no ARC, we must remove the `observer` from default notification center in `dealloc` function, like this:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

otherwise when a binded notification posted, it will triger a crash !

so, the question is how does the `NSNotificationCenter` detect the deallocated `observer` in **ARC**  ?

Comment: my mistake, I found no crash because there is another retain of observer.

Comment: This is evidence that NSNotificationCenter does not retain observers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964041/nsnotificationcenter-why-bother-calling-removeobserver

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** As of iOS 9 and OS X 10.11, it is no longer necessary for an NSNotificationCenter observer to un-register itself when being deallocated. (Source: [Unregistering NSNotificationCenter Observers in iOS 9](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/unregistering-nsnotificationcenter-observers-in-ios-9/))

---

*(Old answer:)* Even with ARC, you have to remove an observer from the notification center when it is deallocated. It may be pure chance that your program did not crash.

The following program demonstrates this. I have activated the "Enable Zombie Objects" option.

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
@end

@implementation  MyObject

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notify:) name:@"test" object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc");
    //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
- (void)notify:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"notify");
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        MyObject *o = [[MyObject alloc] init];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"test" object:nil];
        o = nil; // This causes the object to be deallocated
        // ... and this will crash
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"test" object:nil];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*Output:*

```
notifytest[593:303] notify
notifytest[593:303] dealloc
notifytest[593:303] *** -[MyObject notify:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x100114290
```

Comment: my mistake, I found no crash because there is another retain of observer.

Comment: hm... no crash for me

Comment: @AndreyGagan: You are right, it is no longer necessary. I have updated the answer accordingly. Thanks for the feedback!