# Where is the official mention about observer retain/release of NSNotificationCenter method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter

`NSNotificationCenter` is [known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964041/nsnotificationcenter-why-bother-calling-removeobserver) not to retain/release the observers. It makes sense, and I also have experienced related issue.

Anyway today I realized that I really am not sure on this. [The official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserver:selector:name:object:) doesn't say anything about ref-counting stuffs.

Though its *discussion* section says that we have to unregister the observer before it deallocates, but it doesn't mean the center will not retain them. And deallocation timing can become different by the behavior of the center.

Then, I couldn't find anything from the documentation.

But in practice, we already know the add/remove observer method doesn't retain the observer by experience. Unretained reference is very exceptional behavior which may cause serious bug, then I believe that there should be an explicit mention on this.

Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

No, observers are not retained. That's why when you make an object an observer, you must make sure that it stops observing in its dealloc method. Logically, an observed object should know *nothing* about the observer, shouldn't care about observers, and therefore shouldn't hold a strong reference to observers.